# ec2 boto3 : (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeImageAttribute operation

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-eks, amazon-ami

I am trying to fetch [EKS-Optimized AMI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/eks-optimized-ami.html) latest AMI ID details for "Name" attribute using lambda boto3 like this :

```
ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')
# Get AMI release version of new AMI
    latestAMIVersion = ec2_client.describe_image_attribute(
        Attribute = 'description',
        ImageId = latest_ami_id //AMI ID fetched
    )
```

Though I added "EC2:*" permissions for this, I am getting :

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AuthFailure) when calling the DescribeImageAttribute operation: Not authorized for image:ami-*******b649f",
  "errorType": "ClientError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 29, in lambda_handler\n    ImageId = latest_ami_id\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 391, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 719, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

Same, if I try using CLI

```
aws ec2 describe-images --image-ids <AMI_ID>
```

It is working. I checked [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/errors-overview.html), according to this for "AuthFailure" it should not work on CLI as well. Is it something about "boto3"? Please help me understand.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the Python program is using the same AWS credentials as the AWS CLI? Are both running on the same computer?

Comment: Yes. I am using same aws acocunt & creds. And the python code is executed as part of lambda function. I updated permissions for lambda role but still same.

Comment: What happens if you run that Python code on the same computer as the AWS CLI command? That way, it will use the same credentials as the AWS CLI.

Comment: I tried scenarios like you mentioned, but other than cli, rest places I am getting error, though I try boto3 ec client for other calls like describe_images, it works. Just this "DescribeImageAttribute" giving AuthFailure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with "boto3", it is the parameter I was querying. Briefly, I was trying to get description on AWS Managed SSM Parameter which is EKS-Optimized AMI ID, hence I was facing "AuthFailure", which is not managed by AWS only.